# Where can I acquire a copy of this Doraemon manga?

Tags: merchandise, doraemon

I am the curator of an exhibition on Easter Island in popular culture (http://www.moaiculture.com) and I am trying to track down a few missing items. If you can assist we will acknowledge you in the exhibition. The key question: is this a manga or an activity book?

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or is the website mentioned by the OP not working?

Comment: I think reddit might be more helpful for such discussions as it has much more active userbase in their manga and anime sections